# Finding ggsave and save_plot do not seem to work with the ggdraw+draw_grob from the cowplot package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I cannot seem to save a plot when using `ggdraw()` + `draw_grob()`. Saving just 'plot1' alone works fine but once I start using ggdraw it no longer works with either `ggsave()` or `save_plot()`, it produces an error noting an invalid canvas value. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: replacing previous import 'vctrs::data_frame' by 'tibble::data_frame'
#> when loading 'dplyr'
library(cowplot)
library(grid)


plot1 <-  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cty)) +
          geom_point()

line <-  linesGrob(x = unit(c(0,1), "npc"), y = unit(c(0,1), "npc"))

plot_full <- ggdraw(plot1) +
              draw_grob(line)

ggsave("plotfull.png", plot_full)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in"): invalid value of 'canvas'


save_plot("plotfull.png", plot_full)
#> Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in"): invalid value of 'canvas'
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (both `ggsave` and `save_plot` run without issue).  R version 4.0.2, cowplot_1.1.0, ggplot2_3.3.2

Comment: Thanks for attempting I am also using R 4.02, cowplot 1.1.0, and ggplot2 3.3.2.

Comment: A couple more questions: What OS are you on? Have you tried to open a png device, print the plot, and then close? Have you tried to set a specific png device with `type = ...`. Have you tried to use the `agg_png()` device from the ragg package?

Comment: For saving a plot without using `ggsave()`, follow the process described here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ragg/readme/README.html

Comment: Thanks, I am using windows.  The same error occurs when setting the device with `device=` or `type =`  within `ggsave()`. It works and saves when not using `ggsave()` as per the link you provided.